# How can I find in Sequelize where a divided result is greater than some amount?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 2 columns: `last` and `strike`. I want to find all results where `last / strike` is greater than `10`. I could write a raw query, but I'm trying to see if I can do it the Sequelize way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sequelize.where()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere) combined with [`sequelize.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral)

```js
Model.findAll({
    where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.literal('last/strike'),
        '>',
        10
    )
}).then(instances => {
    // result...
});
```

`sequelize` used above is an instance of Sequelize. This query would generate SQL similar to

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last / strike > 10;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to include other conditions you need to assign the `sequelize.where()` call to some name

```js
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        lastStrike: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.literal('last/strike'),
            '>',
            10
        ),
        something: 4
    }
}).then(instances => {
    // result...
});
```

This would generate the query you mentioned in a comment

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last / strike > 10 AND something = 4;
```

Comment: Can I include other conditions outside of that?
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE last / strike > 10 AND something=4;`

Comment: Yes, but you have to modify the `where` object. I have updated the answer